# Pandas - Trying to create a list or Series in a data frame cell

Tags: numpy, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[74.75, 91.71, 145.66], 'B':[4, 3, 3], 'C':[25.34, 33.52, 54.70]})

        A  B     C
0   74.75  4  25.34
1   91.71  3  33.52
2  145.66  3  54.70
```

I would like to create another column df['D'] that would be a list or series from the first 3 columns suitable for use in another column with the np.irr function that would look like this

```
      D
0     [ -74.75, 2.34, 25.34, 25.34, 25.34]
1     [ -91.71, 33.52, 33.52, 33.52]
2     [-145.66, 54.70, 54.70, 54.70]
```

so I could ultimately do something like this

```
df['E'] = np.irr(df['D'])
```

I did get as far as this

```
 [-df.A[0]]+[df.C[0]]*df.B[0]
```

but it is not quite there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the column `'D'`?

By the way you can easily add it as:

```
df['D'] = [[-df.A[i]]+[df.C[i]]*df.B[i] for i in xrange(len(df))]
df['E'] = df['D'].map(np.irr)
```

if you don't need it, you can directly set `E`

```
df['E'] = [np.irr([-df.A[i]]+[df.C[i]]*df.B[i]) for i in xrange(len(df))]
```

or:

```
df['E'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.irr([-x.A] + [x.C] * x.B), axis=1)
```